# Google maps API Marker

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've got an issue with the Google Maps API. I need to display, like 200 markers on a Google Map. So i do this :

```
$gmap->addMarkerByAddress(location,type,picture);
```

For all my differents markers. And then I do this :

```
$gmap->generate();
echo $gmap->getGoogleMap();
```

It works well, but it takes a lot of time to show the map. I would like to generate the map, and then display the markers one by one on the map, so the user doesn't have to wait 3 minutes to see the results.
Any idea how I could do this ?
Thanks you very much !

EDIT : 
Extra code :

```
$gmap = new GoogleMapAPI('thisismykey');
```

(You can found the content of the GoogleMapAPI here : frenchtoast.fr/friendsmap/examples/GoogleMapAPIclass.txt) And then all the initialization :

```
$gmap->setDivId('test1'); 
$gmap->setDirectionDivId('route'); 
$gmap->setEnableWindowZoom(false); 
$gmap->setEnableAutomaticCenterZoom(true); 
$gmap->setDisplayDirectionFields(true); 
$gmap->setSize(600,600); 
$gmap->setZoom(3); 
$gmap->setDefaultHideMarker(false);
```

I Add my 200 markers with :

```
$gmap->addMarkerByAddress(location,type,picture);
```

And then generate the map

```
$gmap->generate();
echo $gmap->getGoogleMap();
```

Comment: It would take longer to show them one by one

Comment: It's not really important because the user would be able to see the evolution of the results. It won't be a blank page for 3 minutes...

Comment: The only way to figure this out would require you to post more code. It's not possible (for me anyway) to help you without more code.

Comment: Which part do you want ?

Comment: Everything the code references above

Comment: I put the extra code in the first post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not digging through that mess. Please edit your question above with proper formatting.

Comment: Thanks. Now, please post the section of the class that you think is the area that is causing you trouble. I'll help you, but I won't do all the leg work.

Comment: The idea is that I use this 3 functions :
- AddMarker (Who adds a marker)
- Generate (who generate the map)
- GetGoogleMap (who display the map)
And if I generate and display the map. I can't add the markers on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/toomanymarkers.html

Answer (score 0):

If using V2, then I'd try with MarkerClusterer or KML overlay (see Robert's link) depending on the use case.

However, migrating to V3 would get rid of the whole problem because 200 is not "too many" markers any more, and even when you add too many (1000+) the API itself handles them differently to make it easier (and faster) for your browser. And you can still use MarkerClusterer on V3.

For a live example, check this demo. It's V3 but all except FusionTablesLayer are available in V2: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/toomanymarkers/toomanymarkers.html